# Why JQuery .animate() doesn't work as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a div for dragging and dropping files. I would like that once the file is dragged inside the div this increases its height while when the file is dragged out it decreases it.

To do this I used some functions called on the occurrence of the events ondragover and ondragleave.  Using the .css() function to change the height of the div everything works correctly. Using the .animate() function instead something unexpected happens: ondragover calls the function that enlarges the div, but if (without dropping the file) you drag out of the div this does not decrease its height.
I have verified through the console that both events occur and that there are no errors in the console.

Try below by dragging a file in and out of the div without dropping it.

```js
function enter_drop(){
  $("#box").animate({height: "300px"},500);
}

function leave_drop(){
  $("#box").animate({height: "100px"},500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;float:left" ondragover="enter_drop()" ondragleave="leave_drop()"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" draggable="true" style="float:left">
```

Comment: add `draggable="true"` to your example so we can verify

Comment: Try drag the logo over the green div without dropping it. You will see the enlargement. Then drag it outside and nothing will happen

Comment: yes I know, but your initial example wasn't enough to produce this effect

Comment: Btw, @Manuel, I probably should have mentioned this in my answer: you should really replace `.animate()` with [`.velocity()`](http://velocityjs.org/). The difference is big, especially when you start animating more items on your page at the same time. Chances are you'll never want to use `.animate()` again. At production/enterprise level, `velocity` is the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cue's answer is correct regarding the cause of the problem.

However, using `.stop(true)` to stop an outrageously long animation queue is **not** the proper solution. A better approach is to only trigger your animation `ondragenter`: once.

In fact, the best possible solution here is to combine both:

- only trigger `enter_drop` once `ondragenter`...
- ***and*** `.stop(true).animate(...` `ondragleave`, so that if the opening animation is still in progress when leaving, the element doesn't continue the enter animation but, instead, stops at current height position and starts animating back towards `100`.

```js
function enter_drop(){
  $("#box").animate({height: 300},350);
}

function leave_drop(){
  $("#box").stop(true).animate({height: 100},350);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;float:left" ondragenter="enter_drop()" ondragleave="leave_drop()"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" draggable="true" style="width: 100px;">
```

Comment: I didn’t want to assume intention but completely agree.

Answer (score 2):

The `ondragover` is fired constantly when an element is being dragged over a drop target.

jQuery's `.animate()` queue's each callback so when you execute `ondragleave` there are still running animations.

You can use `.stop(true)` to clear the queue'd animations and any subsequent animations will be executed immediately.

```js
function enter_drop(e){
  $("#box").animate({height: "300px"},500);
}

function leave_drop(e){
  $("#box").stop(true).animate({height: "100px"},500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;" ondragover="enter_drop()" ondragleave="leave_drop()"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" style="width:50px;height:50px;" draggable="true">
```